# AngularJS $location preventing browser from following hyperlinks

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue with angularJS's `$location` service. I am using it to retrieve 'GET' parameters from the url. The issue is that it is disabling all hyperlinks on the page(unless opened in a new tab). So if you click on a link it will alter the url but the page stays the same.

What can I do about this?

AngularJS `v1.2.16`

```
var myApp = angular.module('rtApp', [])
    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode(true);
    }])
    .service('Product', ['$http','$location',function($http, $location) {
        var url   = '/shop/product_data.php',
            query = $location.search();

        var service = $http.post(url, query).then(function (r) {
            if (r.status === 200) {
                return r.data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return service;
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a known issue with angularJS's `$location` service.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4608

So the solution is to not use `$location` unless you are using routing.